# ERROR IN SQL SINTAXIS

Tags: mysql

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice * CASE WHEN p.CategoryName IN 'Seafood' ' at line 3

Comment: Saludos. De lo que pones; **p.CategoryName IN 'Seafood'** debe ser **p.CategoryName IN ("Seafood")** *(yo prefiero usar las comillas dobles para o errar con otro símbolo similar)* Recuerda y verifica tengas el **END** del **CASE** donde corresponde.

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).